# Adding a ListView causes the Android App to crash

Tags: android

I have a problem which seems to weird.

The Android application I created is running fine, but when I added a "ListView" element in my `layout.xml` file.
and I still haven't used the ListView in my java class the application refuses to startup.
It simply craches and gives me this Msg : `The application Client (process com.example) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.`

This is my layout.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/filename"/>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/input"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/connect"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Connect"
    android:onClick="Connect"
    />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/download"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Download"
    android:onClick="Download"
    />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/delete"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="List"
    android:onClick="List"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Note: I'm testing on an Android device and not the emulator
Here is a Screenshot of the error I get in logcat: http://img852.imageshack.us/i/screenshotgg.png/

And finally found the sill mistake which caused it not to work
I declared 2 widgets with the same id.

Thnx alot in advance.

Comment: Please post your `layout.xml`

Comment: Please provide `layout.xml` and error report/stack trace (can be found in DDMS or Debug if you are using Eclipse.

Comment: You have a `ClassCastException` being thrown by `onCreate` within `FtpClient.java`.  Please post the code of your `onCreate` method and point out line 42.

Comment: Since you say you have only added a listview and not touched your code, I would suggest you do a clean build and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the LinearLayout. Add `</LinearLayout>` to the end of the xml.

**Edit**: I see that you've uploaded the log. The problem is in your `onCreate`-method on line 42. Please post this method.

Comment: It's already added, if u scroll down in the code I posted up. U will find it.

Comment: This is line 42 in onCreate: 
list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

Comment: I've might have been a bit fast in my conclusion there. That is, that it is the solution if `List` is supposed to be a list..

Comment: Can you post the declaration of `list`? Is `list` defined to be a `List`?

Comment: This is how I declared it---  ListView list;

Comment: I don't think ListView is appropriate. In my applications I use List from Java (import java.util.List), please try to see if this helps. (Specifically I use `List<someObjectType> nameOfVariable;`)

Comment: To NOTE I am using ListView to add to it an adapter will that work if I use the java List

Comment: Yes, it will still work. Anyway, nice you found a working solution. :)

Comment: Anyways I found the silly bug I had in my code and I edited the question to contain my mistake which caused that to happen...

Thanks alot for the help :)